# Как сложить цифры в массиве и изменить таким образом чтобы в нем уже был результат?

Tags: php, массивы

Имею массив:

```
array
(
    [user_25] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 0
        )

    [user_21] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 8
            [3] => 1
        )

)
```

Как сложит все в массиве чтобы на выходе получить вот такой массив.
Понимаю что нужно сделать в `foreach` но не знаю как правильно написать код.

```
array
(
    [user_25] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
        )

    [user_21] => Array
        (
            [0] => 9
        )

)
```

Все что в `[user_25]`, `[user_21]` и так далее нужно сложить.
Помогите.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте `array_map()` в комплекте с `array_sum()`:

```
$arr = [
    'user_25' => [
        0 => 1,
        1 => 3,
        2 => 0
    ],

    'user_21' => [
        0 => 0,
        1 => 0,
        2 => 8,
        3 => 1
    ]
];

$arr = array_map('array_sum', $arr);

var_dump($arr);
```

Результат:

```
array (size=2)
  'user_25' => int 4
  'user_21' => int 9
```

Comment: Тоже хотел скинуть такой вариант, но у меня возникли трудности в условии что значение должно быть первым элементом массива

Comment: Четко, просто и понятно.

Answer (score 2):

Вот так например

```
$array  = array('user1' => array(1,2,3,4,51), 'user2' => array(1,3,4,657,34));

foreach($array as $key => $data){
  $array[$key] = array_sum($array[$key]); 
  //Если нужно что бы `user1` тоже был массивом, тогда 
  //вот так: $array[$key] = array(array_sum($array[$key])); 
}

print_r($array);
```